# UUID not accepted as ID in mongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, uuid

I am trying to use a UUID as the ID of my objects in mongoDB.

The ID is generated based on an email:

```
str(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_URL, email.lower().strip()))
```

When I save the document to the DB I get a TypeError saying that:

```
bson.errors.InvalidId: 'd3ab7243-c756-53d2-8c96-b239b3f19509' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string
```

I've also tried this:

```
from bson.binary import UUID
import uuid

UUID(str(uuid.uuid5(uuid.NAMESPACE_URL, email.lower().strip())))
```

Which also gives me a type error:

```
TypeError: id must be an instance of (bytes, str, ObjectId), not <class 'uuid.UUID'>
```

Looking at this page: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/UUID/#convert-character-string-to-uuid made me believe that this should be possible.

Comment: How is that field defined in the schema?

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can convert a UUID to a string and back again.  Your problem is that a MongoDB ObjectID cannot be a UUID.  It is a 12-byte binary value with a very specific format that is generated BY Mongo.  You don't specify the ObjectID -- Mongo creates it.  If you want a UUID column in your records (which is a very reasonable thing to want), then you need to add your own UUID column.

You can call the ObjectID() function to return a proper object ID, if you want.  That's usually not very useful.